# How to insert an environment variable inside the bash prompt

Tags: bash, environment-variables, prompt

I can set an environment variable inside the bash prompt like this:

```
export PS1="[\u@\H/$FOO \W]\$ "
```

The prompt does not change when I change the environment variable: `$FOO` because the `$FOO` variable is not interpreted.

I can work around it by doing the following, exporting PS1 again.  But I would like to be able to do it on one line:

```
[user@server ]$ echo $FOO
foo
[user@server ]$ export PS1="[$FOO]$ "
[foo]$ export FOO=bla
[bla]$
```

Can this be done in one line?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you need to add backslash to get it evaluated not in the time of FOO assigment but during evaluating the PS1, so do:

```
export PS1="[\$FOO]$ "
```

instead of:

```
export PS1="[$FOO]$ "
```

Note the `\` before the `$FOO`.

Comment: Can you have character escapes in the ```$FOO``` variable though?

Comment: or put the prompt in single quotes: `export PS1='[$FOO]$ '`

Answer (score 19):

Try setting the PROMPT_COMMAND variable:

```
prompt() {
    PS1="[$FOO]$ "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt
```

> From http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html:
>
> Bash provides an environment variable called PROMPT_COMMAND. The contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command just before Bash displays a prompt.