# Stop bash from escaping a string inside a string

Tags: bash, ps1

I've been messing around with `.bashrc`, trying to get a new colored `PS1` that could tell me automagically if I'm using a Python virtualenv. I'm very, very new to Bash, so after some research I created something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
function virtualenv {
    if [ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then
        VIRTUAL=" $BLACK($GREEN`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`$BLACK)"
    else
        VIRTUAL=""
    fi
}

PS1="$BLUE\u@\h\$VIRTUAL $YELLOW\\$ $RESET"
```

in hope that the `$BLACK` and `$GREEN` variables would be interpreted in `PS1`, but instead I got something like this:

```
gabe@notebook \e[30m(\e[32mmyproject\e[30m) $
```

as if Bash was escaping my entire `VIRTUAL` variable, on its own... I've already tried every combination of slash, quotes and commands my limited skill allowed... Any help?

Comment: See Quotes and escaping on the Bash Hackers Wiki: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting You want single quotes on the color strings.

Comment: @ReubenMorais I just tried different combinations of single quotes on the color strings ($BLUE), and in the $VIRTUAL variable. I get either the same result or a literal representation like gabe@notebook $BLACK($GREENmyproject$BLACK)

Comment: What version of bash?  If it's pre-4.x, then it doesn't understand the `\e` escape; you have to use `\033` (or `\x1b`, or literal escape entered by typing control-V, or...) instead.

Comment: @MarkReed bash version 4.2.24. The other colored text works fine, just the ones set inside a different variable that are misbehaving

Comment: your parens may be being interpreted as a call for a sub-shell. Try taking those out for now. Also, simplify your testing further. See if you can't get one color to work first. as Gabe says, the single quotes should protect those variablle values. Search here on stack overflow for `[bash] prompt problems` as this sort of question gets asked pretty regularly. (Your's is a more interesting project than most!). Good luck to all.

Comment: @Gabe Indeed -- best practice is to hardcode all the escapes directly into PS1, and substitute in only values containing 100% printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent bash from substituting variables in strings, when you enclose your string into single quotes

```
VIRTUAL=' $BLACK($GREEN`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`$BLACK)'
```

This will store the string as is in the variable `VIRTUAL`. If you want to substitute parts of it, you must close the single quotes and embed substituting part into double quotes

```
A=x
B=y
C=z

V='$A$B$C'
W='$A'"$B"'$C'
```

will leave `V` as `$A$B$C` and `W` as `$Ay$C`.

Comment: `W='$A'"$B"'$C'` (keeping `$B` quoted against wordsplitting and glob expansion) would be the safer practice.

Answer (score 0):

First -- the virtualenv function isn't going to get called the way you're doing it. The following actually calls your function (which is better not named `virtualenv`) during `PS1` evaluation:

```
function virtualenv_prompt {
    [[ -n $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] && \
      printf %s " $BLACK($GREEN"'$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV"'"$BLACK)"
}

PS1="$BLUE\u@\h"'$(virtualenv_prompt)'" $YELLOW\\$ $RESET"
```

That said, this still won't work the way you want, because `\[` and `\]` escapes (necessary to prevent the shell from calculating color codes as printing characters for purposes of line wrap) need to be directly included in `PS1`, and can't be substituted in.

To make it right, you need to not only add such escapes (if they aren't already in the code definitions), but also move the color codes out of the `virtualenv` function and have them unconditionally present (even if the colors are switching back and forth with no visible contents). See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Answer (score 0):

You escaped the dollar sign here: `\$VIRTUAL`, hence `$VIRTUAL` don't get expanded when assigning to `PS1` (because it becomes a literal `$`, you see).

As a result, `$VIRTUAL` only gets expanded when it's time to generate the prompt, that's why instead of *formatting* you are seeing the *string that defines the formatting*.

Basically you just have to get rid of the `\` in `\$VIRTUAL` when assigning to `PS1`

Comment: I tried that, and forgot to mention... I'm using that backslash to get \$VIRTUAL to be evaluated everytime (a trick I learned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7359870/9835)). If I remove it, the coloring works, but the variable content isn't updated until I load the bashrc again (or reopen a terminal)

Comment: @Gabe Evaluating `$VIRTUAL` every time doesn't do any good if you aren't rerunning the `virtual` function to give it a new value.