# Display Environment Variable in the BASH prompt

Tags: linux, command-prompt, prompt

How can I diplay the environment variable `$STY` in my Linux prompt? I've tried [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359652/insert-a-environment-variable-inside-the-bash-prompt) suggestion, but did not work. Here is what I have:

> PS1='[\e[31;1m]<\u@$(hostname):[\$STY]\w> [\e[0m]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's inside 'single quotes' are taken literally (variable are not **not interpolated**), that's why that doesn't work. Use "double quotes" if you'd like variables to be interpolated...

See :

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

That's the basics of shell !

Comment: Oh yeah, I knew that once.